# Firebase Firestore emulator (TypeError :FieldValue causes error with testing library )

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

---

I am testing server code for a flutter app that uses firebase.

My testframe work consists out of *mocha*, *chai.expect*, and the *firebase emulator (only firestore)* and their respective @types/libraries to write my tests in *typescript*.

Recently, I encountered the problem that whenever an instance FieldValue (e.g. `FieldValue.increment(1), FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`) is called the emulator throws an error:

Example:

```
it('getUniqueNotificationId successful', async () => {
            const db = firebase.initializeAdminApp({ projectId }).firestore();
            FirebaseUtils.setDB(db);

            await db.collection(users).doc(userID).set({
                firstname: firstname,
                uid: userID,
            });

            const notifID = await UserRepository.getUniqueNotificationId(userID);
        });
```

Before I start testing I call `firebase emulators:start --only firestore` to start the firestore emulator.

However, this test case fails with the error:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field notificationId)

The function that I test contains the following code:

```js
async getUniqueNotificationId(userId: string): Promise<number> {

        // Update notificationId field to make it unique again
        const userReference = this.getUserReference(userId);
        //error occurs here:
        await userReference.update(User.getUpdateUniqueIdData());
        

        // Get stored notification id and return it
        const user = await this.getUser(userId);

        return user.notificationId;
    }
```

The error occurs when
`userReference.update()` calls `User.getUpdateUniqueIdData()` which looks like this:

```js
static getUpdateUniqueIdData(): UpdateData {
        return {
            notificationId: FieldValue.increment(1), 
    // FirebaseError: Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field notificationId)
        };
    }
```

I do not really know why this happens because `FieldValue.increment(1)` is valid code and works as expected with the real database.

*What am  doing wrong?*

Meanwhile, code like `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` or `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` can be called in my test cases but cannot be handled by the server code resulting in a similar error.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Cheers,

Charly

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because serverTimestamp() is supported by the emulator. I have it in plenty of tests. Can you put the code causing the error in context? It is not n you example

Comment: I changed to a simpler function that also uses FieldValue.something and added more code for context. I hope it gives you a better overview. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Been having a ton of problems with this as well. I've followed all the advice to use admin.firestore.FieldValue and it works in a stand alone nodejs app but one I use it in a triggered cloud function with the same code it fails.